# Slicing URL with Python

Tags: python, url, string

I am working with a huge list of URL's. Just a quick question I have trying to slice a part of the URL out, see below:

```
http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param2&param3
```

How could I slice out:

```
http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234
```

Sometimes there is more than two parameters after the CONTENT_ITEM_ID and the ID is different each time, I am thinking it can be done by finding the first & and then slicing off the chars before that &, not quite sure how to do this tho.

Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) module. Check this function:

```
import urlparse

def process_url(url, keep_params=('CONTENT_ITEM_ID=',)):
    parsed= urlparse.urlsplit(url)
    filtered_query= '&'.join(
        qry_item
        for qry_item in parsed.query.split('&')
        if qry_item.startswith(keep_params))
    return urlparse.urlunsplit(parsed[:3] + (filtered_query,) + parsed[4:])
```

In your example:

```
>>> process_url(a)
'http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234'
```

This function has the added bonus that it's easier to use if you decide that you also want some more query parameters, or if the order of the parameters is not fixed, as in:

```
>>> url='http://www.domainname.com/page?other_value=xx&param3&CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param1'
>>> process_url(url, ('CONTENT_ITEM_ID', 'other_value'))
'http://www.domainname.com/page?other_value=xx&CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234'
```

Answer (score 4):

The quick and dirty solution is this:

```
>>> "http://something.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param3".split("&")[0]
'http://something.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the split function, with & as a parameter. That way, you'd extract both the base url and both parameters.

```
   url.split("&")
```

returns a list with

```
  ['http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234', 'param2', 'param3']
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out below is what I needed to do:

```
url = "http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param2&param3"
url = url[: url.find("&")]
print url
'http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234'
```

Comment: Careful with this  - if there are no parameters (no "&"), it will just drop the last character from the url.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229352/python-find-question for a better solution.

Comment: Ah I see how that could be a problem and thanks for the warning.  The list I am using always has a parameter after it but I will keep that in mind for the future. :)

Comment: Be careful with url parsing, this most of the time not as easy as it seems. You'd better use the urlparse module, even if it looks like it's easy.

Comment: @Eef:  Always means "mostly".  Never means "Rarely".  As soon as you say "Always", you know it will break because 2 of 14,000 violate your "always" rule.

Comment: @S.Lott: couldn't agree more…

Comment: Cheers for the great advice!! I'm taking all this on board :)

Answer (score 1):

Parsin URL is never as simple I it seems to be, that's why there are the urlparse and urllib modules.

E.G :

```
import urllib
url ="http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param2&param3"
query = urllib.splitquery(url)
result = "?".join((query[0], query[1].split("&")[0]))
print result
'http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234'
```

This is still not 100 % reliable, but much more than splitting it yourself because there are a lot of valid url format that you and me don't know and discover one day in error logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
url = 'http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param2&param3'
m = re.search('(.*?)&', url)
print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [urllib2 file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163009/urllib2-file-name) question for some discussion of this topic.

Also see the "[Python Find Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229352/python-find-question)" question.

Answer (score 0):

This method isn't dependent on the position of the parameter within the url string. This could be refined, I'm sure, but it gets the point across.

```
url = 'http://www.domainname.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1234&param2&param3'
parts = url.split('?')
id = dict(i.split('=') for i in parts[1].split('&'))['CONTENT_ITEM_ID']
new_url = parts[0] + '?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=' + id
```

Answer (score 0):

An ancient question, but still, I'd like to remark that query string paramenters can also be separated by ';' not only '&'.

Answer (score 0):

beside *urlparse* there is also [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl/), which has IMHO better API.