# How to split a web address

Tags: python, string, url, split

So I'm using python to do some parsing of web pages and I want to split the full web address into two parts. Say I have the address http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. I would need the protocol and domain (e.g. http://www.stackoverflow.com) and the path (e.g. /questions/ask). I figured this might be solved by some regex, however I'm not so handy with that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258746/slicing-url-with-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163009/urllib2-file-name

Answer (score 13):

Dan is right: urlparse is your friend:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>>
>>> parts = urlparse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
>>> parts.scheme + "://" + parts.netloc
'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
>>> parts.path
'/questions/ask'
```

**Note**: In Python 3 it's `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Comment: Gotta love that batteries included philosophy.  I thought regex at first b/c I didn't know about that battery was included.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Python urlparse module:

https://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

For a well-defined and well-traveled problem like this, don't bother with writing your own code, let alone your own regular expressions.  They cause too much trouble ;-).

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
protocol, domain = re.match(r"(http://[^/]*)(.*)", url).groups()
```