# Split from a specific delimiter

Tags: python, parsing, url

How to rip a URL like http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php to have a result like this: `www.facebook.com`?

I tried this way, but doesn't work:

```
line.split('/', 2)[2]
```

My problem is probably with that two forward slashes // and some of the URLs start from the www strings.

Thanks for your help, Adia

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a web address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286150/how-to-split-a-web-address)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, we should address how to handle the missing 'http://' for the URLs that 'start from the the www string'. Just using urlparse doesn't cover that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slicing URL with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258746/slicing-url-with-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to look at Python's [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module.

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php')
>>> o.netloc
'www.facebook.com'
```

Comment: Yes, it is better to use appropriate tools for common tasks.

Comment: Note that some of the URLs 'start with the www string'. If the leading 'http://' is missing, urlparse fails to parse this.

Comment: @Paul McGuire : How must I do to vote on a comment? I want to upvote your's

Comment: @Adia : « How to rip a URL LIKE http:// www.facebook.com/pages/create.php » and « Yes, actually some of the URLs don't have the http:// » are contradictory. So grifaton gave an exact answer to your question and a false answer to your problem. But I won't downvote anybody, though.

Comment: @eyquem: sorry if I confused anyone. the facebook URL was just an example and there more URLs in the file I am handling that have all kind of domains and structure. Anyway, from all the posts, now I know how to go about the problem. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best bet would be returning the server part from a regex, ie,

```
\/[a-z0-9\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}\/
```

That can cover www.facebook.com, facebook.com, some-domain.tv, www.some-domain.net, etc.

NOTE: the head and trailing slashes are part of the regex and not regex separators.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
line.split("//", 1)[-1].split("/", 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
ch[7 if ch[0:7]=='http://' else 0:].partition('/')[0]
```

I’m not sure it’s valid for all the cases you’ll encounter

Also:

```
ch[(ch[0:7]=='http://')*7:].partition('/')[0]
```