# Remove every character before the website name in a URL

Tags: python, django

For example if I have `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` I'd like to cut it to `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` or if I have `http://www.samsung.com/au/` I'd like to cut it to `samsung.com/au/`.

I want to make a template tag for this but not sure what to return:

```
def clean_url(url):
    return ?
```

template

```
{{ url|clean_url }}
```

Any idea?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: On advertised posts on my site I want to show the site the post links to - but I want it to look clean without the `https` or `www` etc

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/286194/1081569), but in Python 3 it's `from urllib.parse import urlparse`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, that was uncalled for.  Not everyone has your though process when it comes to typing what to search for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a web address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286150/how-to-split-a-web-address)

Comment: @gahooa https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355550/what-should-i-do-with-a-question-that-is-too-simple

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty way to isolate the domain provided it starts with `something//`

```
def clean(url):
  return url.partition('//')[2].partition('/')[0]
```

Comment: Or just use the quick and clean `urllib.parse.urlparse(url).netloc` :) He wanted to keep the path though, not just the domain.

Answer (score 1):

[urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) will do most of this for you:

```
import urllib.parse
def clean_url(url):
    parts = list(urllib.parse.urlsplit(url))
    parts[0]=""
    cleaned = urllib.parse.urlunsplit(parts)[2:]
    return cleaned
```

Note this does not cut off the "www.", but you shouldn't do that; that can be a critical part of the domain name. If you really want that, add:

```
if cleaned.startswith("www."):
    cleaned = cleaned[4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the use cases, you described. You can just split on the double backslash and go with that or work from there.

```
def clean_url(url):
    clean = url.split('//')[1]
    if clean[0:4] == 'www.':
        return clean[4:]
    return clean
```

However, because the subdomain (such as 'www') can be used as a significant part of the url, you may want to keep that in. For example, www.pizza.com and pizza.com could be links to different pages.

Other things to consider are the urlparse library or regex but they may be overkill for this.